# UNIX script - find files - show dates

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, find

I am running the following command:

```
find . -atime -30
```

However in the output, I would like it to display the time stamp of access time. Also would like it to show the user that accessed the file if at all possible.

Can you help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `printf` option of `find`:

```
find . -atime -30 -printf '%u %Ac %p\n'
```

Take a look at [`man find`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) for the different `printf` formatting options.

Comment: The version of unix I am using doesn't like printf, tried with -print0 but then it complained about '%u %Ac %p\n'.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -atime -30 -print0 | xargs -0 ls -lud
```

You can't determine who accessed the file, this information is not generally recorded.

Bear in mind that atime is not always updated (depends on the file system mount options).

If you want to restrict the find to just files, then you can do:

```
find . -atime -30 -a -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -lud
```

Comment: This does show a result but it is a lot different from the results I get when I type in my original command.

Answer (score 1):

Last access doesn't log the user that accessed the file.

```
find . -atime -30 -exec stat {} +
```

will give you all the info you can get.

If you don't have GNU find or stat, try what Petesh suggests.

Comment: I don't know what version of UNIX you are using. Do you at least have GNU find?

Comment: What I do know is that we are using HP UX.

Comment: So you're probably stuck using xargs and ls

Comment: Yea, and for some reason it still returns the full directory.

Comment: did you use -type f like Petesh suggested. Probably you end up running ls on directories (which will list all the files within it).